# Programmatic changing the Jenkins slave configuration doesn't get reflected in agent config history

Tags: jenkins

I'm programmatically updating or modifying some of the node configuration fields. The changes are getting saved in the node but it is not reflecting in the agent config history.

For example, I'm using setNumExecutors() to update the executor count from 1 to 2. Even though the executor field has been updated with a new value, it is not getting reflected in the "BUILD EXECUTOR STATUS" .i.e the Under BUILD EXECUTOR STATUS I can see 1 idle executor whereas it has to be 2.

The above problem gets resolved when we get into the node configuration and save it manually. Through groovy, I can use setNodes() to solve the issue. But setNodes() sets a list of node but I need to update/reflect the configuration change for a single slave. In my R&D, I can conclude that using setNodes() for a single node is a bad idea as it ends up saving that specific node in the master (other nodes gets disappeared)

Please let me know your thoughts on this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved when I called the setNode() method through getComputer().